# Comodo Firewall blocks Cisco Anyconnect VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, firewall, comodo-firewall, cisco-anyconnect

I am running Comodo Internet Security Firewall (6.3) and trying to connect to work using  Cisco AnyConnect VPN client.  I can make the connection but can't do anything else, not even ping by IP address.

The only solution I've found is to disable the Comodo Firewall Driver.  That solution (along with the alternative: uninstalling Comodo) is mentioned [in this article](https://dotcio.rpi.edu/node/409), but I would like to keep Comodo and the firewall driver in place.

As soon as I deselect the Comodo driver and press OK, things work; as soon as I reselect the driver and press OK, things stop working.  As mentioned in the article, turning the firewall off does not solve the problem.

I tried setting the Alert Frequency to Very High, in an attempt to get a popup message reporting the problem, but this doesn't help.  I've also changed a number of firewall rules to write to the firewall log, but still no clues.

Any other thoughts on how to solve this?

Comment: Use a VPN compatible firewall...

Answer (score 2):

As it is written here https://dotcio.rpi.edu/node/409

There are only two options:

1. - Use Control Panel. Open **Network and Internet** option and there open **Network and Sharing Center**.
   - Select **Change adapter settings**, right-click on **Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client Connection** and there choose **Properties**.
   - Then deselect the Comodo driver and click **OK**.
2. Delete Comodo

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I already mentioned this solution in my question and said that I was looking for something better.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, COMODO had a long history of not being compatible with VPNs however here is workaround:

Open *Comodo->Firewall->Advanced->Network security policy->Add…->Select->Running processess…->System Idle Process (or System if you don’t see System Idle Process)*

Now, you should be back to Application Network Access Control window.

Select **Add…**

**Action:** Allow Protocol,

**IP Direction:** Out,

**Description:** GRE Out Allowed Check, if you want, “Log as a firewall event if this rule is fired”

**Source Address:** Any (or select what you think is better),

**Destination Address:** Any (or select what you think is better),

**IP Details:**  GRE

Hope it could help

Comment: Thanks for the response but this didn't solve the problem.  I turned on logging for this rule (Allow / IP / Outgoing / GRE for System) and didn't see anything.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late answer, but it may help others.

1. Go to Firewall Advanced Settings. 
   Set up a new network zone for the VPN.
2. Still in Firewall Advanced settings,
   create new GLOBAL rules to allow all IP in/out to the VPN network zone.

This will allow pings and `traceroute`
(but `traceroute` must have the `-I` option).

Comment: Windows has `tracert` not `traceroute`. `tracert` does not have a `-I` option.